# Set a default folder for saving the files in C#

Tags: c#, directory

This is my c# code.

But every time I run this code, whenever I click the left click the file is saved in default path : "C:\NewFolder\"

But I don't know how to set the folder selected using right click as my default folder forever.

After I select a folder using right click, whenever I run the exe file, the file should save in that selected folder

```
string folderpath = "C:\\NewFolder\\";
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderpath);
        if (!exists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
        this.Hide();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        SendKeys.Send("{PRTSC}");
        Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
        img.Save(folderpath + "\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".jpg");
        this.Show();
    }
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            folderpath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add application settings :

```
Right click on Project --> Properties --> Settings --> FolderPath | String| User | C:\\NewFolder\\
```

Read the value from the application settings:

```
 string folderpath =Properties.Settings.Default.FolderPath ;
```

When the user right clicks,save the recent settings:

```
if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
{
   DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
   if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       Properties.Settings.Default.folderpath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
       Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default.Folderpath=folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;'     FolderPath in the above code is read-only know. How to modify the value in run time.

Comment: Changer the settings type to User.

Comment: for your reference :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758389/why-are-application-settings-read-only-in-app-config

Answer (score 3):

save your folderpath to your App Settings. then acess it using:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.[settingName]
```

Read this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is more like a comment.

Comment: He is completely right. You can also just store it inside an .INI file. Just store it somewhere outside the application's session. And load it each time a session is created.

Comment: @KevinKal once the link is out dated, the answer will no longer explain the intent,so always add a description for the link. looks better now.

Comment: @KevinKal adding a description to a link is not spoonfeeding !

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. :P