# Application creates folder with "_" in place for space in name when using Properties.Default.Settings

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So case is like, in Assembly Information (for C# Winform Applications), I input like this,

[image: Assembly Information]

Now, When I run it, it creates folder with **_** in name in place of Space, Like this,
[image: Folder with Company Name]

and that folder it creates application folder with some extra text in post fix, Like this,

[image: Folder with Application Name]

So, can anyone help me with this mess?

I want it to create folder with

**ABC Pvt. Ltd.** and not with **ABC_Pvt._Ltd**

and also the sub folder should be

**SampleApplicationDemo**

and not

**SampleApplicationDemo.vsh_Url_hm3mp1cuw1k0q1145wnmcymhrntreeok**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure about this but try to wrap the company name in double quotes

Answer (score 1):

- Press and hold ALT key
- From the keypad press 255 then release the ALT key

This should create a space.

Comment: It worked for **space** but still there is issue of extra **text** automatically added after application name.